# Why does df[df['column'].max()] does not a return a row?

Tags: python, pandas

In this code below `print(df[df['salary'].max()])` returns a `keyError` and does not print the details of employee with the highest salary. However `print(df[df['salary'>=500]])` gives the details of employee i.e their `'name'`, `'age'`, `'email'` and `'salary'`.
`print(df[df['salary']==df['salary'].max()])` does resolve this issue,but why does `df[df['salary'.max()]]` not work.

```
import pandas as pd
details={
        'name':['John','Lidya','Sarah'],
         'age':[21,20,23],
         'email':['john@email.com','sarah@email.com','lidiya@email.com'],
         'salary':[500,650,240]
         }
df=pd.DataFrame(details)
print(df['email'])
print(df[['email','name']])
print(df['age'].max())
print(df.describe(percentiles=[0.2,0.6,0.8]))
print(df[df['salary']>=500])
print(df[df['salary'].max()])
```

Comment: `max` returns a single value, so the dataframe cannot decide on what to do with that. `df['salary']>=500` however returns a boolean, and with that the dataframe can easily filter the rows with that.

Comment: `df['salary'].max()` returns the max value of that column, which is not a valid index for `df`. If you want the row with that value, you need to use `df[df['salary']==df['salary'].max()]`

Comment: better yet just use df.iloc[df['column'].argmax()]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `df['salary'].max() return a value '650'` hence we get a error whereas  `df['salary']>=500 return a boolean value`.

Instead of max use argmax()

```
df.iloc[df.salary.argmax()]
```

Comment: Could you be little more specific

Comment: df['salary'].max() return a integer whereas df['salary']>=500 return a boolean value. So it's better to use argmax as it returns index value which has max value in that column.